# Equations for Elliptic Curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

An elliptic curve $C$ over a field $k$ is a smooth, genus 1 curve defined over $k$ with an associated $k$-rational point. If char$(k) \ne 2$, we can show that $C$ has a model of the form $y^2 = f(x)$ where deg$(f) = 3$. The method I have seen in Silverman and Hartshorne finds this model from a change of coordinates of the general Weierstrass equation which you find via Riemann-Roch. My question involves whether you can see this transformation through a different method.

One can show that $C$ admits a degree 2 map to $\mathbb{P}_k^1$. So, as char($k) \ne 2$, the corresponding extension of function fields is a Kummer extension and hence generated by a square root. Thus, we have an affine curve $y^2 = f(x)$ which is birational to $C$. By Riemann-Hurwitz, there should be 4 ramification points which occur either as roots of $f$ or occur at infinity. Thus, $f$ has degree either 3 or 4.

Is there some way to see that the polynomial $f$ can be chosen to have degree 3? That is, can one see **without explicitly writing our the transformation** that one of the ramification points can be chosen to be at infinity over a **non-algebraically closed** field?

The motivation for this question comes from the case of genus 2 where a hyperelliptic curve of genus 2 has a model of the form $y^2 = f(x)$ where the degree of $f$ is either 5 or 6. One can choose a model where $f$ is of  degree 5 only when $f$ has a root over the given field $k$.

Essentially my question boils down to, is there some way to view from the function field side that you can choose a model $y^2 = f(x)$ where deg($f) = 3$? Also, from the function field side, can you see that there should be a difference in the case of genus 2?

Comment: You have a k-rational point P so use Riemann-Roch to compute dimensions of spaces of global functions with at worst a pole of order n at P, for n=0,1,2,3,4,5. You should get dimensions 1,1,2,3,4,5. If y has a pole of order 2 and x a pole of order 3 at P then both y^2 and x^3 have poles of order 6 and now it's not hard to see that there's a linear relation between 1,y,y^2,y^3,x,xy,x^2. Now complete the square in y if char(k) isn't 2 and you're done. This is surely in Hartshorne or something, and is a bit easy for this site.

Comment: @znt Perhaps my question was not entirely clear. I'm aware of the method you have mentioned, the primary aim of my question is whether you can see this model through a different method. Also, why do you not get an odd degree model in the case of genus 2? I've edited my post so that hopefully it is clearer.

Comment: Would you prefer something along these lines?  We know the curve has a model $Y^2 = P(X)$ with $P$ of degree $3$ or $4$ and some rational point.  Changing projective coordinates, we may assume this point has $X = \infty$.  If $\deg P = 3$ then we're done.  Else $\deg P = 4$ and the leading coefficient of $P$ is a square, so at infinity $P = Q^2 + R$ for some $Q,R$ with rational coefficients such that $\deg Q = 2$ and $\deg Q \leq 1$.  Now write $Y=Q+x$ and get an equation quadratic in $X$ whose discriminant is cubic in $x$.  This gives a birational map from $Y^2 = P(X)$ to $y^2 = cubic(x)$.

Comment: (Inevitably that's not far from the usual Riemann-Roch argument, but is what people actually did in the old days and sometimes still do nowadays.)

Comment: The argument of @Noam D. Elkies is presented in Cassels' little blue book on elliptic curves (where he also explains how to get various other models of genus 1 curves with a rational point into the form y^2=cubic).